# I might have a rare coin

Tags: coins, collectibles

I have a 1944 coin. The back is different. I'm not sure if it has any error since the coin is a bit dirty -- it needs to be cleaned. It does have a mint mark.

Is there anything I can do with this?

Comment: Assuming you live in a moderately sized city, you can take a coin to any coin dealer to get an idea of what it's worth.  Assuming you can identify the country and denomination, you can do a Google search and get a range of values.  For example, if you have a 1944 US wheat penny https://cointrackers.com/coins/13595/1944-wheat-penny/ that has been circulating for 65 years, it's probably worth less than $1.

Comment: But don't clean it before going to a coin dealer. If the wrong cleaning method is used it can be made worthless.